# Table on top of the second column text

Tags: tables, formatting, acm

I have a two column template [From here](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). I want to put a table in the `\textwidth` but the second half of the table appears on top of the text in the second column as it is shown here:

[image]

The script is here:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %to solve the font error
\usepackage{lmodern}  %to solve the font error
\usepackage{underscore} %underscores
%-------------------------for the table-----------------------------        
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tablefootnote}
%-------------------------end table-----------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}


\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\subtitle{Test}

\author{Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ}}
\email{abc@xyz}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here. 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
\toprule
A & B \\ \midrule

AA and BBBB & aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj \\
\hline
AA and BBBB &  aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffggggh000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wide entity in a two-column text must be a float:  it is not a part of the flow.  `tabularx` is not a floating environment, `table*` is. As it is not a floating environment, if you want a caption, you'll have to use the `\captionof` command.

This works:

```
\begin{table*}
  \caption{caption}
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
\toprule
A & B \\ \midrule

AA and BBBB & aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj \\
\hline
AA and BBBB &  aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffggggh000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Also:  *never* use `lmodern` with acmart!  If the package gives you a font error, install the fonts.  Otherwise your manuscript does not satisfy ACM requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Could you try the script without `lmodern`? I could not know what is the missing font and this is the only solution I could find. This the error I get when I comment the `lmodern`:  `Error: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.` `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: This error is usually caused by the absence of libertine font in your system.  You probably need to upgrade your TeX distribution

Answer (score 2):

If you want your table at the point of insertion, you can use the `strip` environment, from the  `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle):

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %to solve the font error
\usepackage{lmodern} %to solve the font error
\usepackage{underscore} %underscores
%-------------------------for the table-----------------------------
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tablefootnote}
%-------------------------end table-----------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cuted}
% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}
%\begin{strip}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\subtitle{Test}

\author{Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ}}
\email{abc@xyz}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{strip}
 \centering \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l >{\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
A & B \\ \midrule

AA and BBBB & aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj \\
\hline
AA and BBBB & aaaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffggggh000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 000000 000000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{strip}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It hurts to use another extra package, but this answer actually worked for me.

Comment: @Haini: Well, one cannot always reinvent the wheel! :-)